# Microservices - managing external system auth-token

Tags: authentication, microservices

Lets say I have 2 Microservices (customer and payment), both consume APIs of external system (e.g. Stripe).

API Authentication

- Assume that before consuming any business API of Stripe, API Consumer (in my case Customer & Payment Service) has to first authentication itself using API Keys (AppId and secret).
- Stripe provides access token which must be passed into HTTP header into subsequent API  calls to Stripe.

below can be possible approaches,

Approach1
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BGn-hiNwZT4u3BIBmEv-HkJC0w0dk5CB/view?usp=sharing

Approach2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JA1hFq7l7-4Ow3b32XNyb2co4tqxKZQ6/view?usp=sharing

Approach1

- Multiple auth token though Stripe account is single (per service instance)
- Each service to manage auth token expiration/renewal

Approach2

- Single auth-token exists with all services.
- dependency on auth service.
- auth token expiration/renewal managed by single service (Auth Service)

would like know which should be best fit in Microservice architecture? Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Approach 2 is slightly more scalable and maintainable if more services will require API access to external APIs.
However the correct implementation would be an egress gateway for all your external API calls.
If your going to spend the time to build an Auth service, you might as well go all the way and centralize your external API routing as well.
Benefits:

- Single internal endpoint for external APIs, reduces duplication.
- Handles all authn and authz with external APIs for your services.
- Centralizes all logging, auditing, disaster recover, load balancing etc....

Most gateway products like kong can be used for egress as well.